# Расположение элементов HTML по кругу

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Всем здравствуйте!

Только начинаю осваиваться с web-программированием, но решил с самого начала делать все правильно: красиво и по стандартам, а то что у меня пока получилось по моему вопросу я бы красивым не назвал.  Необходимо сверстать страницу следующего вида:

[image]

В общем-то я все уже сверстал с помощью CSS-свойств position (absolute), top и left с необходимыми значениями (с футером только беда - он вверх поднимается, но я просто задал фиксированную высоту тому блоку, в котором все это отображается, и вроде все нормально). Но что-то мне подсказывает, что это все можно было сделать... красивее что-ли, по правильному в общем.  Никто никогда не сталкивался с подобной задачей? Или может теоретически что подскажет?

P.S. Встречал примеры подобного расположения картинок с помощью javascript (можно было бы переделать под себя), но хочется справиться только с помощью HTML и CSS.

Answer (score 5):

Можно взять готовый плагин jQuery [Radmenu](http://www.tikku.com/jquery-radmenu-plugin).

Можно позиционировать JavaScript'ом.

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
var delta = Math.PI * 2 / divs.length;
var x = 0, y = 0, angle = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    divs[i].style.position = 'absolute';
    divs[i].style.left =  100 * Math.cos(angle) + 'px';
    divs[i].style.top = 100 * Math.sin(angle) + 'px';

    angle += delta;
}
```

И думаю, можно поисследовать возможности SVG для HTML5.