# Как сверстать круг по окружности которого равномерно расположено несколько маленьких кружков

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, анимация

Ниже рисунок, что необходимо сделать

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я попытался, но маленькие окружности располагаются неравномерно по большой окружности. Есть ли какой-нибудь способ, формула, чтобы не высчитывать положение каждой окружности.
Я также пытался изменить окраску маленьких окружностей в копиях, созданных командой `<use>` но они  остаются того же цвета, что и оригинал

`<use xlink:href="#crcMin" x="0" y="0" style="fill:yellow;"/>`

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">  
    <defs> 
      <circle id="crcMin" cx="200" cy="60" r="25" fill="#DADADA" stroke-width="2" stroke="#DADADA" />
    </defs> 
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#41424A" />
    <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="140" fill="none" stroke-width="4" stroke="#DADADA" /> 
  
  <use xlink:href="#crcMin" x="0" y="0" style="fill:yellow;"/>
   <use xlink:href="#crcMin" x="60" y="20" />
     <use xlink:href="#crcMin" x="100" y="60" />
     <use xlink:href="#crcMin" x="140" y="100" />
  
  <rect x="165" y="25" width="70" height="70" fill="none" stroke="#DADADA" stroke-width="4" stroke-dasharray="10 50 10 0"/>
  
  </svg>
```

Как равномерно распределить маленькие окружности по краю большой окружности и реализовать последовательный переход желтого цвета от одной окружности к другой.

Comment: Отвечающие на этом сайте ставят минусы и закрывают вопросы, если они напоминают ТЗ. Пожалуйста, дополните вопрос [**собственными попытками**](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) справиться с заданием. Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных, отличная формулировка xDD

Comment: А если по существу: рисуете окржность, в её центр помещаете кружочки, потом делите 360 на кол-во кружочков, и по теореме Пифагора зная угол и радиус (гипотенузу) смещаете ... общая концепция какая-то такая.

Comment: Автора вопроса уже наверное не найдешь. Да и не надо ему похоже это. А вот три содержательных  ответа жалко.  Переформулировал вопрос. Хорошо бы его переоткрыть.

Comment: Автор, спасибо за хороший вопрос.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Решение SVG

Решение адаптивно, работает во всех браузерах включая `IE11`, `Edge`

Вы можете изменить начальные размеры блока, меняя проценты `width` и `height` блока контейнера.

```css
.container{
width:50%;
height:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 400 400" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">  
    <defs> 
      <circle id="crcMin" cx="200" cy="60" r="25" fill="#DADADA" stroke-width="2" stroke="#DADADA" />
    </defs> 
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#41424A" />
    <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="140" fill="none" stroke-width="4" stroke="#DADADA" />
    <use xlink:href="#crcMin" />
    <use xlink:href="#crcMin" transform="rotate(45 200 200)"/> 
    <use xlink:href="#crcMin" transform="rotate(90 200 200)"/>
    <use xlink:href="#crcMin" transform="rotate(135 200 200)"/> 
    <use xlink:href="#crcMin" transform="rotate(180 200 200)"/>
    <use xlink:href="#crcMin" transform="rotate(225 200 200)"/>
    <use xlink:href="#crcMin" transform="rotate(270 200 200)"/> 
    <use xlink:href="#crcMin" transform="rotate(315 200 200)"/>
    <rect x="165" y="25" width="70" height="70" fill="none" stroke="#DADADA" stroke-width="2">
      <rect x="165" y="25" width="70" height="70" fill="none" stroke="#DADADA" stroke-width="4" stroke-dasharray="10 50 10 0"/>
    </rect> 
    <text x="100" y="210" font-size="28" font-weight="700" font-family="sans-serif" fill="#DADADA"> OPTION NAME </text>
  </svg>  
</div>
```

### Вариант с анимацией

Не работает только в `IE` и `Edge`, потому что браузеры микрософт не поддерживает анимацию SMIL SVG. [Как в прочем и многое другое не поддерживают `IE11`, `Edge` и в анимации CSS.](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/csstransitionsanimationsforsvgelements/)

```css
.container {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">  
    <defs> 
      <circle id="crcMin" cx="200" cy="60" r="25"  stroke-width="2" stroke="#DADADA"/>
    </defs> 
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#41424A" />
    <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="140" fill="none" stroke-width="4" stroke="#DADADA" />
    <g fill="#DADADA">
      <use xlink:href="#crcMin" fill="#FFDD00">
        <animateTransform id="sc" attributeName="transform" type="scale" values="1;3;1" dur="1s" begin="rot.end" />
      </use>
      <use xlink:href="#crcMin" transform="rotate(45 200 200)" /> 
      <use xlink:href="#crcMin" transform="rotate(90 200 200)" />
      <use xlink:href="#crcMin" transform="rotate(135 200 200)" /> 
      <use xlink:href="#crcMin" transform="rotate(180 200 200)" />
      <use xlink:href="#crcMin" transform="rotate(225 200 200)" />
      <use xlink:href="#crcMin" transform="rotate(270 200 200)" /> 
      <use xlink:href="#crcMin" transform="rotate(315 200 200)" />
      <animateTransform id="rot" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" values="0 200 200;45 200 200;90 200 200;135 200 200;180 200 200;225 200 200;270 200 200;315 200 200;360 200 200;360 200 200" begin="0;sc.end" dur="6s" calcMode="discrete" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze" /> 
    </g>
    <rect x="165" y="25" width="70" height="70" fill="none" stroke="#DADADA" stroke-width="2" />
    <rect x="165" y="25" width="70" height="70" fill="none" stroke="#FFDD00" stroke-width="4" stroke-dasharray="10 50 10 0">
    <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" values="280;245" dur="2s" calcMode="discrete" repeatCount="indefinite" fill="freeze" /> 
    </rect> 
    <text x="100" y="210" font-size="28" font-weight="700" font-family="sans-serif" fill="#DADADA"> OPTION NAME </text>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

Как вам такое решение?)))

```css
.square {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #000;
  position: relative;
}

.main-circle {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.small-circle-box {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  position: absolute;
}

.angle {
  position: absolute;
  border: solid #fff;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}

.angle-0 {
  top: -4px;
  left: -4px;
  border-width: 4px 0 0 4px;
}

.angle-1 {
  top: -4px;
  right: -4px;
  border-width: 4px 4px 0 0;
}

.angle-2 {
  bottom: -4px;
  right: -4px;
  border-width: 0 4px 4px 0;
}

.angle-3 {
  bottom: -4px;
  left: -4px;
  border-width: 0 0 4px 4px;
}

.no-border {
  border: none;
}

.small-circle {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.box-0 {
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

.box-1 {
  top: 3%;
  right: 3%;
}

.box-2 {
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateX(50%) translateY(-50%);
}

.box-3 {
  bottom: 3%;
  right: 3%;
}

.box-4 {
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(50%);
}

.box-5 {
  bottom: 3%;
  left: 3%;
}

.box-6 {
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

.box-7 {
  top: 3%;
  left: 3%;
}

.name {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="square">
  <div class="main-circle">
    <div class="name">OPTION NAME</div>
    <div class="small-circle-box box-0">
      <div class="small-circle"></div>
      <div class="angle angle-0"></div>
      <div class="angle angle-1"></div>
      <div class="angle angle-2"></div>
      <div class="angle angle-3"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="small-circle-box box-1 no-border">
      <div class="small-circle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="small-circle-box box-2 no-border">
      <div class="small-circle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="small-circle-box box-3 no-border">
      <div class="small-circle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="small-circle-box box-4 no-border">
      <div class="small-circle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="small-circle-box box-5 no-border">
      <div class="small-circle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="small-circle-box box-6 no-border">
      <div class="small-circle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="small-circle-box box-7 no-border">
      <div class="small-circle"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно сделать с помощью `JS`:
**P.S.** *формула взята [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/94953/280567)*

```js
var circle = document.getElementsByClassName('circle');
var delta = Math.PI * 2 / circle.length;
var angle = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < circle.length; i++) {
  circle[i].style.top = 100 * Math.cos(angle) + 'px';
  circle[i].style.left = 100 * Math.sin(angle) + 'px';
  angle += delta;
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  margin: 6rem;
}

.wrapper::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-38%, -38%);
  display: block;
  width: 13rem;
  height: 13rem;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.wrapper .circle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.wrapper .name {
  font-size: 2rem;
  transform: translate(-15%, 15%);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="name">Name</div>
</div>
```